# Rename Misspelled Categorical values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, categorical-data

I have a categorical variable with some values misspelled or "unknown"/"unspecified". Is there a way to rename these specific values with the most common (in my case "Computer")? Thanks!

```
df['platform'].value_counts()
Out[41]: 
Computer       5433941
Tablet         4415217
Mobile         4229074
Unspecified    1716370
Unknown          48113
Big screen        9850
UNKNOWN            269
comp                 1
Name: platform, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to replaces label and use apply on your column.

```
to_replace = ['Unspecified','Unknown]
target = 'Computer'
def label_restrictor(label,to_replace=to_replace,target=target):
    if label in to_replace:
        return(target)
    else:
        return(label)
```

Then you apply this function to your concerned column :

```
df.platform.apply((lambda label: label_restrictor(label)),inplace=True)
```

And voilà!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I tried, but I'm getting this error:

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'

Comment: I added parenthesis around the function, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace = ['Unspecified', 'Unknown']
final_value = df['platform'].value_counts().idxmax()
def replace_values(x):
    if x in replace:
        return final_value
    else:
        return x
df['platform'] = df['platform'].apply(replace_values)
```

Using `idxmax`, you can get the value with maximum frequency. Then use the `apply` function to replace value

if you also have null values in platforms column:

```
df['platform'] = df['platform'].apply(lambda x: replace_values(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

Comment: amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If it answered your question, you can accept the answer.

Comment: if I would like to generalize your function to any variable, would this work?

Comment: def replace_values(x):
    if x in replace:
        return x.value_counts().idxmax()
    else:
        return x

Comment: No. That wouldn't work. `value_counts` is a series function. While x is just a value of the column you're applying this function too.

Comment: This function is already generalized. You just need to change the `final_value`, depending on the column. And the use `apply` on the required column. You also might need to change the `replace` list.