# How to rename multiple spellings of a categorical variable as one value

Tags: variables, rename, categorical

A number of values in column have similar but differently spelled names.

How do I combine the different spellings as one categorical value?

array(['Individual', 'Trust', 'LLC', nan, 'individual', 'Partnership',
'INdividual', 'Corporation', 'Individual ', 'Corporation ',
'Trust '], dtype=object)

I want to combine all spellings of individual, corporation, and trust.
Then I want to combine all individual and non-trusts as one new dummy variable.

I found 'Rename Misspelled Categorical values in Python'[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850352/rename-misspelled-categorical-values-in-python#new-answer?newreg=49de6d138c29496e9ba66622cc76dd7e), but the code didn't seem applicable.
Also, looked up lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

#replace various substrings

```
#replace different spellings of individual
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('individual', 'Individual')
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('INdividual', 'Individual')
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('Individual ', 'Individual')

#replace different spellings of trust
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('Trust ', 'Trust')

#replace spellings of corporation
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('Corporation ', 'Corporation')
```